# Spark - adding multiple columns under the same when condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to add a couple of columns to a Spark DataFrame.
The value for both columns is conditional, using a `when` clause, but the condition is the same for both of them.

```scala
val df: DataFrame = ???

df
  .withColumn("colA", when(col("condition").isNull, f1).otherwise(f2))
  .withColumn("colB", when(col("condition").isNull, f3).otherwise(f4))
```

Since the condition in both `when` clauses is the same, is there a way I can rewrite this without repeating myself? I don't mean just extracting the condition to a variable, but actually reducing it to a single `when` clause, to avoid having to run the test multiple times on the DataFrame.

Also, in case I leave it like that, will Spark calculate the condition twice, or will it be able to optimize the work plan and run it only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding columns `f1`/`f3` and `f2`/`f4` can be packed into an array and then separated into two different columns after evaluating the condition.

```scala
df.withColumn("colAB", when(col("condition").isNull, array('f1, 'f3)).otherwise(array('f2, 'f4)))
      .withColumn("colA", 'colAB(0))
      .withColumn("colB", 'colAB(1))
```

The [physical plans](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#explain():Unit) for my code and the code in the question are (ignoring the intermediate column `colAB`) the same:

```
== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [f1#16, f2#17, f3#18, f4#19, condition#20, colA#71, colB#78]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [f1#16, f2#17, f3#18, f4#19, condition#20, colAB#47, colA#54, colB#62]
```

so in both cases the condition is evaluated only once. This is at least true if `condition` is a regular column.

A reason to combine the two `when` statements could be that the code is better readable, although this judgement depends on the reader.